# is there a code that allows the textbox input in numbers?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a program of Airline management in C# windows form, I have a sign up form and there are two fields (textbox) I want to take values in numbers.

> Textbox1 (Phone Number)
> Textbox2 (National Identity card number)

I want these textboxes to take input in 11 and 16 Numeric Digits respectively.

While I want the Textbox to take input in a restricted way with (-) dash such as

> ####-####### (for Textbox1)

> #####-#######-# (for Textbox2)

Also,  where to put the code in which block?

Comment: Are you looking for `MaskedTextBox` control?

Comment: Maybe I am not sure, this is my first time using C#

Comment: Agree with Dmitry; this is a job for MaskedTextBox. Read about it here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Answer (score -4):

I set 'MaxLength' for Textbox1 and Textbox2 based on your example:

> ####-####### (for Textbox1) 'MaxLength'=12

> #####-#######-# (for Textbox2) 'MaxLength'=15

```
    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        //Switch is faster than if
        switch (!((e.KeyCode >= Keys.D0 && e.KeyCode <= Keys.D9) || (e.KeyCode >= Keys.NumPad0 && e.KeyCode <= Keys.NumPad9) || e.KeyCode == Keys.Back || e.KeyCode == Keys.Home || e.KeyCode == Keys.End || e.KeyCode == Keys.Left || e.KeyCode == Keys.Right))
        {
            case true:
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;//Non-numeric characters are not written with this command
                break;
            default:
                switch (e.KeyCode != Keys.Back && e.KeyCode != Keys.Home && e.KeyCode != Keys.End && e.KeyCode != Keys.Left && e.KeyCode != Keys.Right)
                {
                    case true:
                        //This is how the total number of separators is calculated
                        byte j = 0;
                        for (byte i = 0; i < textBox1.Text.Length; i++)
                        {
                            switch (textBox1.Text[i] == '-')
                            {
                                case true:
                                    j++;
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                        //You can change this section, based on your country's national identification code or phone number
                        switch (j < 5)//Check total separators
                        {
                            case true:
                                switch (textBox1.Text.Length)
                                {
                                    case 4:
                                        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + '-';
                                        textBox1.Select(textBox1.TextLength, textBox1.TextLength);
                                        break;
                                }
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void textBox2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        //Switch is faster than if
        switch (!((e.KeyCode >= Keys.D0 && e.KeyCode <= Keys.D9) || (e.KeyCode >= Keys.NumPad0 && e.KeyCode <= Keys.NumPad9) || e.KeyCode == Keys.Back || e.KeyCode == Keys.Home || e.KeyCode == Keys.End || e.KeyCode == Keys.Left || e.KeyCode == Keys.Right))
        {
            case true:
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;//Non-numeric characters are not written with this command
                break;
            default:
                switch (e.KeyCode != Keys.Back && e.KeyCode != Keys.Home && e.KeyCode != Keys.End && e.KeyCode != Keys.Left && e.KeyCode != Keys.Right)
                {
                    case true:
                        //This is how the total number of separators is calculated
                        byte j = 0;
                        for (byte i = 0; i < textBox2.Text.Length; i++)
                        {
                            switch (textBox2.Text[i] == '-')
                            {
                                case true:
                                    j++;
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                        //You can change this section, based on your country's national identification code or phone number
                        switch (j < 14)//Check total separators
                        {
                            case true:
                                switch (textBox2.Text.Length)
                                {
                                    case 5:
                                        textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + '-';
                                        textBox2.Select(textBox2.TextLength, textBox2.TextLength);
                                        break;
                                    case 13:
                                        textBox2.Text = textBox2.Text + '-';
                                        textBox2.Select(textBox2.TextLength, textBox2.TextLength);
                                        break;
                                }
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Tested in:

Visual Studio 2017, .NET Framework 4.5.2, Windows Forms

Thanks

Comment: Note: if this solution helps you, please mark as answer (don't forget to vote for me)

Comment: If your country's language is right to left, let me know to update the solution.

Comment: Please add an explanation of how you solved this instead of just posting code. Code-only answers are usually less useful.

Comment: I can't help but say the switch statements are horrid, switch is not faster than if using less than 5 cases. Not to mention the increased complexity.

Comment: Um, no, there's no such thing as security through complexity.

Comment: When you simply can not read it, it means it is safer.